# Is SipHash a secure alternative to HMAC-SHA256 for user authentication?

Tags: authentication, authorization

After reading the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SipHash) about SipHash I think it can be used like HMAC-SHA256 in JWT to create and verify API tokens (authenticate client devices).

In JWT the server creates this MAC to sign user identifiers (e.g. a number or email) with a private key which is then sent alongside the identifier with every request (after login).

Furthermore, the official paper states:

> Target applications include network traffic authentication

However, I can't find *any* pages on the web explaining this use case although it is much faster and has been out for a while.

Is HMAC-SHA256 more secure in any way or am I missing anything else? Thank you!

EDIT: SipHash output is typically only 64bit, so I am referring to SipHash double with 128bit like in the [JavaScript implementation](https://github.com/jedisct1/siphash-js)

Comment: if it ain't broke, don't roll your own. it might be fine, but more people are more sure that sha256 is fine.

Comment: I'm rather asking out of interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The newer, 128-bit output version of SipHash is conjecturally appropriate for this task; i.e., *if SipHash is as strong as its authors intend* (if!), then yes, you can use it for that task.

An analogous remark can be said of SHA-2, but the main issue here is one of subjective confidence; cryptographers haven't examined SipHash in nearly as much detail as SHA-2, so subjectively, we have fewer reasons to believe it is as strong as it's conjectured to be, compared to HMAC-SHA-2.

So HMAC-SHA-2 is the more prudent option here.  I would only consider using SipHash if I'd conclusively shown, based on profiling data, that SHA-2 was a significant performance bottleneck for my application.

Answer (score 2):

SipHash only generates 64 bits of output; thus, it is dramatically less secure than SHA-256, SHA-384, or SHA-512.  It is also faster, which aids an attacker as well.  The first 64 bits is reasonable, but SipHash stops there.  See [this Crypto.Stackexchange post](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/27478/12082) for more details.

Further, you shouldn't be using a single pass of anything for user authentiation (password hashing); use PBKDF2, BCrypt, SCrypt, or Argon2 with as high an iteration count/work factor as your hardware can afford.  See [How to securely hash passwords](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/39623)

Comment: i don't PW hashing (derivation) is what's meant by OP for auth, given the mention of hmac, which seems to point to some kind of nonce+sharedSecret routine.

Comment: Yes, I didn't mean key derivation but client authentication (generate a MAC for a user identifier by the server which is then transmitted with every request by the client to prove that he is who he claims to be).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that it's 64bit of output generally, but there is also a double version with 128 output, for example in the [JavaScript implementation](https://github.com/jedisct1/siphash-js). Is this one hard to brute force + secure then?